# Stacked Bar Chart count by a certain column which contains string values

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I used seaborn to get a barchart where my data is counted by the column `MONTH`.

```
sns.catplot(x = 'MONTH',kind="count",data=df)
```

What I now wanted to get is a stacked barchart where the data is counted by another column `TASKTYPE`. The entries in this column are strings.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
MONTH TASKTYPE
09/19 A
09/19 B
10/19 B
10/19 B
01/20 A
```

I now want to get a stacked bar chart with `MONTH` on the x-axis, `count` on y-axis and the bars stacked by `TASKTYPE`. I think I could do something like this using pandas.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.groupby('MONTH')['TASKTYPE'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to naturally sort/order x-axis by `MONTH`? Note: `MONTH` is a string value, do I have to set it to datetime at first?

Answer (score 2):

It's straight forward with matplotlib.  Just shape your data first. Convert to date and back to string to get ordering you want

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""MONTH TASKTYPE
09/19 A
09/19 B
10/19 B
10/19 B
01/20 A"""), sep="\s+")

(df
 .assign(m=pd.to_datetime("28/"+df["MONTH"]))
 .groupby(["m","TASKTYPE"])["TASKTYPE"].count().to_frame()
 .unstack(0)
 .droplevel(0, axis=1)
 .T
  .assign(MONTH=lambda dfa: dfa.index.strftime("%m/%y"))
  .set_index("MONTH")
 .plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you :-) And how could I order the x-axis chronologically instead of lexicographically?